# How can I get links in Views Slideshow to link to different URLs than just one as defined in views?

Tags: views

I think I am a little closer to getting my links to work, but I am running into an issue that makes my link point to something like: /content/statshttp://lacrosse.college.edu/content/stats
I am trying to make it so that the maintainer of the website can just enter in the relative URL they want the link to point to.
I have included screen shots of two areas that I think may be causing this.
[image: screen shot]
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the answer is that I needed to set the Formatter of the link to be set to the default. You can see in the picture that I was trying different formatting options, but the default is what I needed.